# Sending an invoice per email goes to primary address, not to billing

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, email, invoice, 4.6.10

I am  not sure if I overlooked a setting or if it could be considered to be a bug.

When we do a search on contributions and with the results we select "Print or Email Contribution Invoices" and we select Email, the invoices are sent to the Primary email address for the contact, but we need them to go to their "Billing" email addresses (Which I think is logical for an invoice).

Is this a setting I overlooked, a feature (I don't understand) or a bug?

Comment: I think this should be considered a bug or at least an issue of handling billing information in a coherent way. I recently open up a suggestion to improve the handling of billing addresses - but totally forgot about email-addresses... Will add a remark to the jira issue (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17784)

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting that you overlooked. Since Billing is not necessarily utilised it sounds like you requirement is a setting that says 'set my system to email to Billing email if it exists, otherwise send it to Primary'
(NB I realise I may not be adding much to above comments but am trying to get some unanswered questions answered as that is currently the 'weakest' aspect of our Beta civicrm stackexchange according to these [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm))